Keep getting "Gcloud Pub/Sub: Total timeout of API google.pubsub.v1.Publisher exceeded 60000 milliseconds"
I am new to GCP and I've developed a simple Google Cloud Run service that reads a CSV file from a Google Cloud Storage bucket and pushes each row to Pub/Sub. The code functions well on the emulator for both small and large files, but when deployed on GCP, I encounter errors with large files
Total timeout of API google.pubsub.v1.Publisher exceeded 60000 milliseconds  before any response was received.
I am using batching and flow control for pub/sub so theoretically, there should be no "backed up" requests to pub/sub
const topic = pubsub.topic(pubSubTopic, {
  batching: { maxMessages: BATCH_SIZE, maxMilliseconds: 100 },
  flowControlOptions: {
    maxOutstandingMessages: 50,
    maxOutstandingBytes: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
  },
});

const flow = topic.flowControlled();

and here is the function that pushes data to pub/sub
async function processFileInBackground(
  file,
  listId,
  docRef,
  contactTypeColumn
) {
  const rows = [];
  const contactTypeCounts = {};
  const totalRows=0;


  const stream = file.createReadStream().pipe(csvParser());

  stream.on("data", async (row) => {

    row.listId = listId;
    totalRows++;

    const wait = flow.publish({ data: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(row)) });

    if (wait) {
      await wait;
      console.log(`Published message after waiting`);
    }

  });

  stream.on("end", async () => {

    await docRef.update({ totalRows});

    console.log(`File processing completed for listId: ${listId}`);
  });

  stream.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("Error processing file:", err);
  });
}

Google recommended to make sure that cloud run service has enough resources and I have verified that CPU never goes over 40% utilization and memory stays under 20%
This is the exact error that I get
GoogleError: Total timeout of API google.pubsub.v1.Publisher exceeded 60000 milliseconds  before any response was received.
    at repeat (/usr/src/app/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:66:31)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:108:25)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {

Any help/pointers will be really appreciated
I have tried
batch publishing,
non-batch publishing,
I have tried exponential backoff
I have tried increasing the timeout for pubsub
and other techniques but was never able to get this work

Your code is taking over 60 seconds to execute. Either improve the efficiency, reduce the size of the CSV that your Function is processing, or increase the timeout. Note: your function should execute in milliseconds. Long CPU runtimes will be expensive.

A couple of things:
First, I'm streaming the data into Pub/Sub, so theoretically, the data is being pushed to Pub/Sub continuously, right?
Also, there are times when you need to process large files. But this isn't even a large file—it's just 13MB.
